# Erro ao chamar método no code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
using System;
using Treinamento.DTO.Global;
using Treinamento.BLL;
namespace Treinamento.WEB.Tabelas.cidade
{
public partial class Listar : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = CidadeBLL.Instance.Listar();
        GridView1.DataBind();

        if (GridView1.Rows.Count == 0)
            LabelMensagem.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs 
    e)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Listar' and no extension method 'Listar' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Treinamento.WEB C:\Users\danilo.costa\Desktop\TreinamentoNET\source\Treinamento.WEB\Tabelas\cidade\Listar.aspx.cs   10  Active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CidadeBLL.Instance`não possui o método `Listar()` ou não foi inicializado da forma correta.